# How to Put Custom Taxanomy Meta Box in Main Column

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox

WordPress added the Custom Taxonomy Meta box at sidebar, Is there any way which we can relocate it in the main column , Under Edit box?

Thansk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately WP is [hardcoded to generate taxonomy metaboxes in that `side` location](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.5/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L126).

It is tad fragile, but possible to throw generated data around from one location to another:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'move_taxonomy_metabox' );

function move_taxonomy_metabox() {

    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    $taxonomy    = 'test';
    $metabox_key = 'tagsdiv-' . $taxonomy; // or $taxonomy . 'div' if hierarhical

    if ( isset( $wp_meta_boxes['post']['side']['core'][$metabox_key] ) ) {

        $metabox = $wp_meta_boxes['post']['side']['core'][$metabox_key];
        unset( $wp_meta_boxes['post']['side']['core'][$metabox_key] );
        $wp_meta_boxes['post']['normal']['core'][$metabox_key] = $metabox;
    }
}
```

More proper way might be to just nuke generated metabox and completely redo registration.

Comment: Hi Rarst, thanks for your comment and code but I didn't exactly get what do you mean by" generated metabox and completely redo registration"? Do you mean I can create a Custom Taxanomy inside a new Custom Meta Box? Once again Thanks for your hint

Comment: @Behseini I meant to completely replicate `add_meta_box()` call core does (which I linked to), changing location from `side` to `normal`.